# Odt file, shown with all styles

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I'm using odt file as some kind of template and Libre Office as tool to create this template. It usually works fine except one thing.

Let assume our odt file has a paragraph of text.

```
There is my text.
```

XML file may or may not look (seems random) like this (messy, not very good thing for for parsing or as a template):

```
<text:p text:style-name="P7">There is</text:p><text:p text:style-name="P7"> my text<text:p text:style-name="P7">.</text:p></text:p>
```

Sometimes it's (again seems random) like this (expected result, makes sense after all):

```
<text:p text:style-name="P7">There is my text.</text:p>
```

Is there any way to get rid superfluous xml tags? Or at least can user see a raw document in LibreOffice/OpenOffice to manually remove redundancy?

The key is to provide easy tool for a user, to detect and fix artefacts like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Ctrl-M?  If all formatting is defined in styles and style formatting is not manually overridden, it should not disturb the formatting but should remove redundant tags.

A tedious user process would be to cut and paste-special as text and apply style again.

Finally, a macro would definitely do the trick.

Comment: Im not so sure if cut-paste combo will work. But we will try, also Ctrl-M might help. For now, your answer is winning. :) Thank you.